# Dual Setup Ubuntu / Windows

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, games

I am trying to set up a dual boot configuration and could need some advice regarding the partitioning of my drives.
First of all what do i want to achieve... I will use windows mainly for gaming and am planing to do my work in linux.

My system currently has 2 SSD's.
1. 240gb (system only drive)
2. 500gb (used for my gaming library only)

My documents/files/videos are all stored on a NAS drive. I sometimes do work on my ssds temporary if the task is speed up doing so.

I've read that when reinstalling windows it often overwrites the grup boot loader for linux. So my question is, which setup would make more sense?

1 - 240gb drive -> linux / 500gb drive --> windows + gaming library

2 - 240gb drive - linux + windows / 500gb drive --> gaming library

i think #1 would give me the benefit of having more storage for my gaming library... 240gb should be enough to have a small windows partition + linux. But maybe its more difficult to maintain (reinstalling systems)

what scenario would be preferable and what partition sizes would you advice?

Comment: It doesn't make much difference. It is a matter of opinions. This kind of quetions are usually closed here. because there is no correct answer.

Comment: Ah ok thank you. I thought it might make a difference when reinstalling windows and disconnecting the second drive with linux. If its the same, then i guess i will go with scenario #1

Comment: It maybe slightly more difficult to re-install Windows, but not really difficult.